# Not able to install tree using brew

Tags: tree, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am unable to install tree command using 'brew install tree'. I am getting the following output:

```
>Updating Homebrew...
>fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
>Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "tree".
>==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
>Error: No similarly named formulae found.
>==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
>Error: No previously deleted formula found.
>==> Searching taps on GitHub...
>Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Note that i am using macOS Big Sur version 11.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when first trying to use brew on M1.

Run `brew doctor` and if brew was not installed correctly you will see the message below. Running the first two commands "tapped the homebrew" correctly for me. Good luck!

> Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
> rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
> brew tap homebrew/core

> Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may
> not receive updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the
> default branch with:
> git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master

Comment: Hey thanks git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master works for me